# Bulk processing via Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have the following use case.

Find all opportunities whose "estimated close date" is within 7 days of today and update one of its fields.

I thought of implementing this via Process Builder but looks like the process builder cannot simply do a mass processing without any DML entry criteria.

Am I right ?.

Can the above mentioned requirement can be implemented via process builder ?

What are other alternatives (I can think of batch apex....is there something else?)

**EDIT :**
Adding more info

Opportunity O has a 1:1 lookup relationship with Asset A.

A's parent Object is DeltaBuild D.

D has a date field "Complete Date".

This complete date in D is available in O via cross object formula field (O.X)

Our use case is that all opportunities where O.X is within a week from today() then a field update has to happen and an email alert is to be sent.

I believe that this process cannot be done via TimeBased WF because we will not know when D.CompleteDate field will be populated.

Also we can't base this timebased wf even from DeltaBuild Object also because D has 1:many relationship with Asset A.

If our use case can indeed be done via timebased wf then I and my client will be happy..:)

Would appreciate any pointers :)

Comment: Is this an ongoing process, or just a once off?  have you tried time based workflow, or the scheduled actions in the process builder?

Comment: This is an ongoing process...hmm..looks we really need to use scheduled apex...the client really wanted to "non code" based solution...We explored the timebased wf...but it really would not suit our use case

Comment: Are there any AppExchange products available comparable to scheduled apex ???...Spinning a scheduled apex is easier but the client wants something that they can configure by themselves without being much reliant on dev availability

Comment: Why won't the time based workflow or the schedule actions suit your use case?  keep in mind, the schedule actions I'm referring to are the ones defined in the process  builder, not the apex scheduled methods.  We currently use a range of time based workflow rules for the expiry of an item, with email reminders being sent 6 weeks before hand and fields being updated.  It works well once the system has been set up. data migration is a different story.

Comment: @NickCook : I have added more info ..please provide your inputs as to whether this is indeed feasible via TimeBased WF or scheduled actions

Answer (score 0):

You can always include a checkbox on the record to trigger the process, and teach your client a simple dataload tool like Apsona or Dataloader.io